# Content Porter Error -Unable to get the list of Child items

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

While doing content Porting(Exporting). I am getting error `Unable to get the list of Child items` when selected a publication.

I have observed also when above error is shown in Content Porter. I am seeing a Kernel error in event logs.

```
Unable to execute method TDSE.GetWFE
The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Config\Tridion.ContentManager.config)

Error Code:
0x80131902 (-2146232062)

Call stack:
WFE.Initialize
UtilitiesTDS.GetWFEObject
TDSE.GetWFE
```

We Tried with older Tridion.config files that didn't help.

Comment: Did you already try to restart COM+, IIS and the SDL Content Porter Service?

Comment: Yes I have done restarting IIS Services and COM+. Didn't help.

Comment: Did the user with which you have logged into the Content Porter have access right on the CM server and the different folders on CM server (temp, SDL Tridion Installation folder etc.)

Comment: Even with Tridion Admin(domain) account content exporting is not working. The same account is working in our other environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically whenever you see the message:

> The configuration file has been changed by another program.

That is an indication that the config file has been changed but not all SDL Tridion services have been restarted after that change. The restarting of the services is required because at first start of a service it reads the configuration file and caches its values. While the service does recognize the change, it does not automatically reload the file.

So, to solve the error (as you found already) just restart your server (or the services).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was tridion configuration file was locked by a user(Opened in edit mode).

We closed the session and restarted IIS Services and COM+.